# What's the differences between a local node.js server and a python simple http server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to build a D3.js chart locally. So I have my csv file and my index.html in the same folder on my Desktop. When I'm running my python local server everything run perfectly but when I'm running a node.js sever with the following code :

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
    {
        console.log('test');
        response.write('test');
        response.end();
    });

server.listen(8000);
```

it doesn't work.

So my question : What's the differences between a python local server and a node.js local server. What should I do to make my node.js local server working the same way my python local server does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Express**

Your server in node is correct , but it will always send the response as `test`. Since you need to serve the static files of your project, you can use express.

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Assuming your files are placed inside the folder named `public`. and has similar structure.

```
|package.json
|server.js
|public
  - files
```

The python SimpleHTTPServer works because it host the current directory (from wherever it is evoked)

**If you do not want to use express**
you can create it using pure node.js. [Here is the link to a gist, that i found useful](https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/701407)

```
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs")
    port = process.argv[2] || 8888;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname
    , filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

  path.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("404 Not Found\n");
      response.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) filename += '/index.html';

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
      if(err) {        
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(err + "\n");
        response.end();
        return;
      }

      response.writeHead(200);
      response.write(file, "binary");
      response.end();
    });
  });
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));

console.log("Static file server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

Comment: I discovered the same difference between Python SimpleHTTPServer and Node. This thread helped me. Solution using express is working fine. Solution without express is no longer working:  path.exist has been removed, and shall be changed with fs.exists(). Some other changes are maybe required

Answer (score 0):

You are trying two different things completely, both python and node open a socket and listen for http communication, however, node requires the following configuration:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

And then from the command line:

```
node example.js
```

In simple words, both of those scripts create a socket that listens to connections, I even encourage you to run them both at the same time so you can understand what is happening.

Python HTTP uses python libraries for creating and listening, and node uses different ones.